# Disply zero value in cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

Is there any other way to display zero value in excel without using ' before zero.

with zero before ' then it show zero in excel

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible (and normal) but you need to supply more information. What is displayed when you enter 0 in the cell (without the apostrophe) and what is the cell formatting applied to that cell?

Answer (score 4):

Check this setting in Excel (make sure it's on to display `0`'s)

[image]

Also check the Cell's `Number Format` - its made up of up to 4 parts, the third is for Zero values.  If the third field is blank `0`'s won't be displayed